# pandas reindexing error while using loc to create a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, reindex

There are many questions on re indexing, I tried the solutions but they dint work for my code, may be i got something wrong, I have a data set with two variables patnum(ID), vrddat(Date) and I'm using below code to get the data frame after applying certain conditions.

```
data_3 = data_2.loc[(((data_2.groupby('patnum').first()['vrddat']> datetime.date(2012,1,1)) & 
     (data_2.groupby('patnum').first()['vrddat']> datetime.date(2012,3,31)))),['patnum','vrddat','drug']].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Above code is throwing below error.

> IndexingError
>
> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided

How do I get a new data frame having all the variables as input data after applying conditions, In the above code conditions work but when i'm using loc to get a new data frame with all the variables it's throwing Indexing error, I used reset_index as well but it dint work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem you want use boolean indexing in `DataFrame` `data_2` by mask created from `Series` `s`, so need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check values in column `vrddat` by `vals`:

```
data_2 = pd.DataFrame({'patnum':[1,2,3,3,1],
                   'vrddat':pd.date_range('2012-01-10', periods=5, freq='1m'),
                   'drug':[7,8,9,7,5],
                   'zzz ':[1,3,5,6,7]})

print (data_2)
   drug  patnum     vrddat  zzz 
0     7       1 2012-01-31     1
1     8       2 2012-02-29     3
2     9       3 2012-03-31     5
3     7       3 2012-04-30     6
4     5       1 2012-05-31     7
```

---

```
s = data_2.groupby('patnum')['vrddat'].first()
print (s)
patnum
1   2012-01-31
2   2012-02-29
3   2012-03-31
Name: vrddat, dtype: datetime64[ns]

mask = (s > datetime.date(2012,1,1)) & (s < datetime.date(2012,3,31))
print (mask)
patnum
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: vrddat, dtype: bool

vals = s[mask]
print (vals)
patnum
1   2012-01-31
2   2012-02-29
Name: vrddat, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
data_3 = data_2.loc[data_2['vrddat'].isin(vals), ['patnum','vrddat','drug']]
               .reset_index(drop = True)
print (data_3)
   patnum     vrddat  drug
0       1 2012-01-31     7
1       2 2012-02-29     8
```

---

Another faster solution for `s` is [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
s = data_2.drop_duplicates(['patnum'])['vrddat']
print (s)
0   2012-01-31
1   2012-02-29
2   2012-03-31
Name: vrddat, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```